# MacOS Ethernet en0 not working - Mysterious error

Tags: macos, mac, ethernet, network-adapter

I have older Mac Mini, suddenly the Ethernet connection stops working. When I connect to same network by Wi-Fi it gets correct IP address from DHCP and everything works. When I try to connect with "en0" Ethernet my Mac gets wrong IP address (169.254.x.x) Network is not working even if I set IP manually.

Strange thing is that when I change configuration in "Device" tab to "Manual" correct IP address shows for a second, than it shows "Disconnected" and "connected" and gets wrong IP.

I tried different cables, ports on router, removed/added en0, changed MAC on en0, reset of all equipment... nothing works...

Router shows status "Incomplete" in ARP table at this MAC/IP.

Video on YT: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYrwiSBMigs

Please help me!